# How to set the featured cover image of a webpage?

Tags: html

I want to know the URL of the featured image of a webpage.
As in facebook, when you post a link as a comment, it automatically shows an image once posted. How can I know the URL of ANY featured image of a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the browser's devtools by right-clicking on the image(the element) and click "inspect" or "inspect element" -depending on browser-, then try to find that exact element and see the link assigned to it `<img>` (or `background-image` url in css style, if it's not an `<img>` element).